# java android , delay inside onclick button includes gui changes

Tags: java, android

I am trying to simulate an sending msg progress .
The main idea is to colour the members who message sent to them, promote the status bar etc.. (gui changes ) all this with delay for each loop iteration.

The main problem is that everything is going inside the onClick listener and runing thread inside it wont help ): cause gui is changing only after delay is completed.

Any one may advice me how to do this simulation ?

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                        for(int i=0; i<phoneNumbers.size(); i++){

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            }


                            members.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            members.get(i).invalidate();
                            mProgressDialog.setProgress(i+1);
                            sentCount.setText(getString(R.string.msgSentCount) + (i+1));

                            if(i==12){
                            scroolView.animate().translationYBy(-50);}

                        }
            }
        });
```

Thanks you very much !

Comment: For what Thread.sleep(1000);?

Comment: Use Handler.postDelayed

Comment: Your app is crashing because you are doing the Thread waiting on the main UI thread. Try doing the waiting in a task or use Handler.postDelayed like @Alex recommends.

Comment: how do i use handler.postDelayed with loop ?                                        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
          Handler handler = new Handler();
          handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
               members.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
              }
          }, 1000*i);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly got it works with recursion !!!!

```
public static int counter=0;
public void runMother(final Handler handler)
{
if(counter==3)return;
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        members.get(counter).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        counter++;
        runMother(handler);

    }
}, 1000*counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I unserstood you right - fake progress + waiting time. First of all handlers a perferct to delay an output:

```
    //Fake Progress
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    open(this);


    // Delay output
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setData();
        }
    }, 6000);
```

in the function setData(), do the task you wanna run after
and progress bar for fake:

```
    public void open(Activity activity) {
       progress.setMessage("Fakeprogress,  Data Mining...");
       progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
       progress.setIndeterminate(false);
       progress.setCancelable(false);
       progress.setMax(100);
       progress.setProgress(10);
       progress.show();
       final int totalProgressTime = 100;

       final Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int jumpTime = 0;
            while (jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
                try {
                    sleep(60);
                    //System.out.println("********" + jumpTime);
                    jumpTime += 1;
                    progress.setProgress(0);
                    progress.setProgress(jumpTime);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            progress.dismiss();

        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```